# Can we enforce two boundary conditions for a second order PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, parabolic-pde

Suppose we try to solve a second order PDE on a finite interval $[a,b]$, for concreteness, let us consider the heat equation $\partial_t u = \partial_{xx} u$ on $x \in (a,b)$ with some smooth initial condition $u_0(x)$. I am wondering whether the PDE is still well-posed if we impose Dirichlet as well as Neumann boundary condition simultaneously. i.e., we require $u(a,t) = u(b,t) = 0$ and $\partial_x u(a,t) = \partial_x u(b,t) = 0$ for any $t > 0$. Assume that the initial datum $u_0(x)$ is compatible with the boundary constraints as well (i.e., $u_0(a) = u_0(b) = 0$ and $\partial_x u_0(a) = \partial_x u_0(b) = 0$). May I know is it too crazy to put two different types of boundary conditions at the same time in this scenario? Does the resulting initial-boundary-value-problem still admits a unique classical solution? Thanks for any help!

Edit: Based on Rhys' comment, it seems that if we require a non-trivial solution when both type of boundary conditions are enforced, we need the original PDE problem (with only the Dirichlet BC or Neumann BC) to have multiple solutions (non-uniqueness...) Probably that's the reason why I haven't seen any sort of thing like this... (impose different types of BC for a PDE problem). I would also like to know whether someone is aware of such type of problems that is well-posed. (Obviously, heat equation here is a "bad" example).

Comment: Suppose $u_D$ solves the problem with only Dirichlet conditions, and $u_N$ solves the Neumann version. Then, if $u_D$ and $u_N$ are unique (as I recall, they are) then you require $u_D=u_N$ for the unique solution to the problem with both.

Comment: Following Rhys' comment above, considering the non-trivial solutions to the Dirichlet and Neumann problems on a finite interval are known to be $u_{D} \propto \sin$ and $u_{N} \propto \cos$, then the only solution would be $u \equiv 0$, so the problem would have no solution if $u_{0} \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make my comment into an answer.

The Dirichlet and Neumann conditions can both be considered separately, as they are independent. In other words, you can find the sets $$\mathfrak D=\{u\mid u \text{ solves Dirichlet version} \}$$ $$\mathfrak N =\{u\mid u \text{ solves Neumann version} \}$$

and then your solutions to the combined problem are the set $\mathfrak D \cap \mathfrak N$

Further, it would be well-posed if both the respective parts are well posed.

Answer (score 4):

In Rhys' answer he split the boundary into Dirichlet and Neumann components, which will make the problem well-posed. A different interpretation is imposing **both** Dirichlet and Neumann conditions over the whole domain. This leads to an overdetermined problem, which is not solvable in general domains. The question then becomes *which domains admit solutions to the problem?*

For concreteness, a classical example of this is *Serrin's problem* in which one asks which domains $\Omega$ admit a function $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C^1(\bar{\Omega})$ that satisfies \begin{equation*}
\left \{ \begin{array}{rcll}
-\Delta u &=& 1 & \text{in } \Omega \\ u&=& 0 & \text{on } \partial \Omega \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} &=& \text{constant} & \text{on } \partial \Omega .
\end{array} \right . 
\end{equation*} Serrin proved that the only such domain was if $\Omega$ is a ball.

Overdetermined problems often lead to free boundary problems (i.e problems in which the boundary/ a portion of the boundary are *a priori* not know) which is a particularly rich and active field of current research.

Comment: Thanks for this informative answer. It's good for me to know "Serrin's problem" anyway!