# Heat equation with Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

### The Problem

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ be open and bounded with $C^2$-boundary. Let $T>0$ and $u\in C^{1,2}\left((0,T)\times\Omega\right)$ be a solution of the heat equation
$$\partial_t u-\Delta u=0\qquad\text{in }(0,T)\times\Omega$$
subject to a Dirichlet boundary condition
$$u=0\qquad\text{on }(0,T)\times\partial\Omega$$
**and** a Neumann boundary condition
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0\qquad\text{on }(0,T)\times\partial\Omega.$$
Intuitively, I would say that the trivial solution $u=0$ is the only one, but I'm having trouble to show this.

**My Question: Are there non-trivial solutions to the equation described above?**

### Remarks and Observations

I was working on my master's thesis, when I stumbled across the above problem. There, I had an additional assumption that $u\leq 0$ in $(0,T)\times\Omega$. In this special case, there is indeed only the trivial solution:

The strong maximum principle implies that any non-trivial solution must satisfy $u<0$ everywhere in $(0,T)\times\Omega$ and hence we can make use of a boundary point lemma (e.g. Lieberman: Second Order Parabolic Differential Equations, Lemma 2.6) to find $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}>0$ on $(0,T)\times\partial\Omega$.

Also, in the general case, but assuming $T=\infty$, mass conservation and standard energy estimates imply that
$$\int_\Omega u\ \mathrm{d}x=0.$$
However, this certainly doesn't help for small $T$ and even if we knew this, I don't see where we could go from there.

Finally, in the case the answer to my question turns out to by yes, does this also hold for more general (linear) second-order parabolic pde?

Comment: No uniqueness, not unless you say something about the initial condition.

Comment: @Hussein Do you happen to have any justification or reference to support your claim? I couldn't find anything myself and would be very interested to see it. From my point of view imposing a second boundary condition instead of an initial condition may very well imply uniqueness.

Comment: never mind me. I misread the problem.

Comment: @msgcas . A really interesting question that troubled me for one week now. At last google found a [similar question about Poisson's equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4153554/can-we-enforce-two-boundary-conditions-for-a-second-order-pde/4154510) with a really interesting answer.

Comment: @KurtG. This is indeed a very interesting result. It may be worth thinking about which domains may admit a non-trivial solution. That said, there is of course an important difference of this question compared to Serrin's problem: Serrin's problem is really over-determined (Poisson's equation + Dirichlet boundary already implies uniqueness) which is not the case for this question as we do not impose an initial condition. Also, I still strongly believe that non-trivial solutions doesn't exist (for any domain), although I've not been able to prove it even in one dimension.

Comment: @KurtG. JackT mentioned in his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4153554/can-we-enforce-two-boundary-conditions-for-a-second-order-pde/4154510) that such problems are often closely related to free boundary problems. I must admit, however, that I fail to see the exact connection: If $u$ were a solution and we extend it by zero outside of the domain, it will in general not be twice continuously differentiable on the boundary.

Comment: @msgcas . I have never worked on free boundary problems and cannot comment on that. Intuitively I agree with you that the answer to your question above there is no. Mostly because I failed to construct  a counter example (where $u$ can be positive or negative) for the heat equation in $[0,\infty)\times\mathbb R$.